# Can't connect to any remote mongoDb

Tags: remote-access, ubuntu-14.04, mongodb

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 and am unable to connect to any remote mongodb server on my home network. I'm pretty sure it worked only a month ago. Furthermore, I have no problems connecting from my work network.

For example, I have an aws server running mongodb. I can ssh to it, but trying to connect with mongo results in the uniform connection error ("couldn't connect to server... connection attempt failed").

Any suggestions on how I can troubleshoot this?

EDIT: I just confirmed the same behavior on a windows machine. Could it have to do with my ISP?

EDIT 2: turns out it was a problem with the router. I'd still be interested to know of there's any way to identify where the issue is from the computer, without going to the router. Though even if I had looked at the router I wouldn't have known that it was blocking all non-standard ports.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your mongo instance is running, by doing

```
sudo service mongod status
```

If your mongo is not running, then you can either write:

```
sudo service mongod start
```

OR

if you have conf setup with auth, then write:

```
mongod --auth --configure /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

Comment: I don't understand how the answer is related to the question. I'm not trying to connect to a local mongod server. I'm trying to connect to remote hosted mongo instances.

Comment: This is just a heads up whether you're connected to mongodb or not. 2nd step will be to check if you've authorised access or not, and last wuld be to check mongodb error log file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my understanding is that you are trying to access the mongodb server you set up at home from other environment, and you failed.
My suggestion is that if you can access your mongodb server at home, and you cannot access it from your AWS server or windows laptop, it should be a network problem, most likely a firewall? Do you have firewall within your OS? If not, maybe you can ask your ISP about it~

Comment: Yeah I have no firewalls set up. I'm sure it had to do with my home network. But the problem persisted for 2 days and then disappeared without me doing anything. So I honestly have no clue. I had no problem accessing local mongodb at home either.

Comment: So it seems to be a network problem, though it's hard to locate the problem now :P

Just hope you are not hacked lol

Comment: Hm well it came back the next day. Turns out my router's time had come. Had to go get it replaced.

Comment: hah good to know~